# What are these Groovy closures containing only identifiers in Gradle build scripts?

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures

Reading Gradle build scripts I keep coming across code such as

```
configurations {
  myConfig
}
```

I understand that this code calls the function `configurations` with the closure `{ myConfig }`. But what kind of closure body is that? It just references some undefined thing called `myConfig`. How does this closure ever do anything when run? After all, the following code

```
def myClosure = { foo }
myClosure()
```

predictably yields `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo for class: Main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy can look really strange when omitting parentheses.  Throw in closure delegates and metaprogramming and things can be very different than other languages.  Gradle is a mix of declarative configuration, and imperative  code implemented in DSL code wrapper, and so the line of between "I'm Configuring this" vs "I'm writing code to do this" is fuzzy for sure.  At the end of the day it is just running code, BUT this is one of those times where thinking about it from a "this is all just code" perspective can make you go "Wat!?"

The `configurations` block is a [ConfigurationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html), and containers are very flexible entities where the elements within it can be whatever you want.  Maybe if we rewrote it like this it'd be a little less weird:

```
configurations {
   dev {
   }
   staging {
   }
   production {
   }
}
```

When someone writes `myConfig` without the parentheses it's the same as an empty Closure block.  Which would mean effectively accepting the defaults.
Now, I've replaced myConfig with more familiar more concrete examples of (dev, staging, production).  But you can imagine that we might want to make configurations flexible and the client could define anything here that fits his/her environment.  Also notice that I added empty Closure blocks after to show those [Configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) could be further configured with properties like:

```
configurations {
   dev {
      description = "Used for local development only."
   }
   staging {
      description = "Can be deployed to the staging environment only."
   }
   production {
      description = "The environment deployed to customer facing system."
   }
}
```

Now how is all of this implemented under the hood?  Well it's really pretty simple once you understand how `delegate` property functions in groovy Closures.  If you were implementing the `ConfigurationContainer` ourselves you'd do something like this (this is loose idea pseudo code):

```
public class ConfigurationContainer {

   Map<String,Config> configs = [:]

   def methodMissing(String name, def args) {
      configs[ name ] = new Config( name )
      Closure c = args.first()
      c.delegate = configs[ name ]
      c.call()
   }
}

class Config {
   boolean debug = false
}
```

Now, this isn't exactly how it's done if you go look at Groovy code (see NamedDomainObjectContainer if you want to create something like this), but you can think of it like this.

1. I'm using metaprogramming method `methodMissing` to capture any configuration name the user declares (ie dev, staging, production, aws, azure, etc).
2. Creating a `Config` object that presumably contains some properties that this block wants to configure.
3. I'm grabbing the first argument (ie expecting a Closure)
4. Set the `delegate` of the `Closure` to my `Config` object.
5. Invoking the closure with `call()`

Now any call to a property or method within that closure will **delegate** it to the instance set on the `delegate` property.  It's like writing `config.debug` in the closure without needing to say `config.`.  The closure *knows* you what you mean.

Which means if we were doing this hypothetical thing in Gradle our code could become:

```
configurations {
   dev {
      debug = true
   }
   staging {
      debug = true
   }
   production
}
```

because our `Config` object already has a default of `debug = false` and production just needs to be declared, but not configured.

The concept of the `delegate` is what was missing when you tried to invoke the `Closure` yourself.  Without setting the `delegate` property the code within the `Closure` didn't know how to find those properties and throw a `MisingPropertyException`.

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy you can assign [delegates](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy) to closures, that are objects that will be used to resolve the properties and methods used in the closure.

An example would be to assign a map to the closure

```
def map = [foo: "bar"]

def myClosure = { foo }
myClosure.delegate = map
myClosure()
```

This will print `bar`.

Try it with the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxLSU1TyE0sULBViE7Lz7dSUEpKLFKK5eJKAYlXOufkF5cWpQJlqxWA0gq1XHAxvZTUnNT0xBKQJNAAhISGJheXAhIAABqcHZw)

Delegates can also implement [methodMissing](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing) or [propertyMissing](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_propertymissing) to react to dynamic properties.